# Can we proof a scavenged transformer of unknown specification?

Tags: transformer, safety, specifications

This step-down transformer was scavenged from a power tool battery charger.  It was designed to take 120V AC current and it outputs 20V AC.

I can't find any specs for it, so I'm wondering what assumptions one can make about using it.

1. Since the wires are 16 AWG can we assume it's safe to run at up to 10A?  Or could it be internally more constricted?  Can we "proof" it for a current *X* by running it at *X* for a few minutes and confirming that voltage and current don't drop significantly, and that its temperature stays below, say, 40C?
2. The input contacts are separated by one inch.  Is it safe to run the transformer in reverse (step-up): I.e., can we connect the output to 120V AC and take 720V off the other side?  Or without knowing its rating does that risk arcing the windings on that side and destroying the transformer?  If we're willing to risk destroying it does running it successfully at that voltage for some "burn-in" period confirm that it is safe to operate at that voltage?

[image: Tansformer]

Comment: 2. is almost certainly a bad idea. Darn near to being a "dead" certainty, even.

Comment: And not to be a wise guy at all, but how can you be 100% sure it is simply a transformer, and not a switching supply module? The latter has become cheaper to produce than the traditional transformer followed by rectification and brute force filtering, and manufacturers really like the word "cheap". :-)

Comment: http://www.sklaic.info/electronics/transformer/transformer.php

Comment: @Randy - Is it not certain by construction?  Perhaps not as clear from the one picture, but it has laminated outer brackets and the input and output terminals bind to windings that circle opposite sides of the core.

Comment: If you can buy them, somebody makes 'em so go speak with them: http://www.plccenter.co.uk/en-GB/Buy/WINBOND/6608T21T?redirect=true or here: http://winbond.by-trade-shows.com/EI-66-transformer.html

Comment: @feetwet Well yes... based on that I'm sure there is a transformer in there. But of course form the picture the size isn't apparent, and you must realize that SMPS modules *DO* have transformers too... but since the incoming power initially hits an oscillator (often called a "chopper" in that case), the frequency going into the transformer is much higher then typical line frequency, thus allowing a very small transformer to do the job. But you can see where such a module could never be reversed, even is an ordinary transformer sometimes can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the wires are 16 AWG can we assume it's safe to run at up to 10A? Or could it be internally more constricted?

Based on apparent dimensions, the current rating is almost certainly less than 10A. Measure the laminations carefully and estimate the rating by comparing with published data for similar transformers.

> Can we "proof" it for a current X by running it at X for a few minutes and confirming that voltage and current don't drop significantly, and that its temperature stays below, say, 40C?

Such a test would take more than a few minutes. Winding temperature rise should be determined by resistance. Search "temperature rise by resistance." You will need to select an appropriate and conservative value for maximum temperature rise.

> Is it safe to run the transformer in reverse (step-up): I.e., can we connect the output to 120V AC and take 720V off the other side?

Absolutely not. You can use it in reverse by applying no more than 20 volts to the 20-volt terminals. More than that will cause the transformer to saturate, draw too much no-load current and overheat.

Answer (score 1):

The transformer will be safe up to a maximum temperature. If you can keep your hand on it (so <60C) it will be OK. It may be OK hotter. You can derive a duty cycle versus loading with several runs at different loadings.

You cannot run a transformer backwards. 120v into a 20v winding will best case blow the fuse, worst case blow the transformer.